# How to extract text between two words in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, select

This is the source string:

```
random foobar "name" : "Jack Ryan", other random stuff
```

In Oracle query, how do I extract Jack Ryan from it?

I guess I am looking for whatever is between `"name" : "` and `",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(col, '.*"name" : "([^"]+)".*', '\1')
```

You can also use `regexp_substr()`:

```
regexp_substr(col, '"name" : "([^"]+)"', 1, 1, null, 1)
```

This captures the portion of the string within double quotes that follows string  `'"name" : '`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a829fb565ab8f0bfd57173976adbf734)**:

```
with t as (select 'random foobar "name" : "Jack Ryan", other random stuff' col from dual)
select 
    col, 
    regexp_replace(col, '.*"name" : "([^"]+)".*', '\1') newcol1,
    regexp_substr(col, '"name" : "([^"]+)"', 1, 1, null, 1) newcol2
from t
```

```
COL                                                    | NEWCOL1   | NEWCOL2  
:----------------------------------------------------- | :-------- | :--------
random foobar "name" : "Jack Ryan", other random stuff | Jack Ryan | Jack Ryan
```

Comment: Thanks. A followup question - what if I needed to find the second instance of this pattern?

Comment: @Stubborn: you can use `regexp_substr()` and set the fourth argument to `2` instead of `1`.